# Progressbar shows larger in Swiperefreshlayout

Tags: android, listview, android-progressbar, tabview

I have tabview with listview, progressbar showing very large in the listview, I tried to set 30dp to width and height and also match_parent but not working. The progressbar is loading in onPreexecure method.

here is my listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ProgressBar>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycleView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Here is my output screenshot
[image]

Comment: try adding a Relative layout after the SwipeRefreshLayout and put the rest of the code inside it

Comment: Thats cool!! Its working.

Comment: happy to help, accept and upvote my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `SwipeRefreshLayout` class it says

> This layout should be made the parent of the view that will be
>   refreshed as a   result of the gesture and can only support one direct
>   child. This view will   also be made the target of the gesture and
>   will be forced to match both the   width and the height supplied in
>   this layout.

So try adding a Relative layout after the SwipeRefreshLayout and put the rest of the code inside it